# Why is Angular reporting errors from my node_modules folder?

Tags: angular, npm

When running `ng serve`, it successfully starts serving but then lists a bunch of errors such as:

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.02 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 689 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.89 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 341 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2021-05-19T14:16:23.633Z - Hash: a3c27b44ab59c4ca8e77 - Time: 22993ms

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscription.ts:33:13 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Subscription | Subscription[]'.

33   protected _parentOrParents: Subscription | Subscription[] = null;

... more errors ...


** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4222, open your browser on http://localhost:4222/ **
```

When opening that URL in my browser, I get the single output of `Cannot GET /`.

I have tried deleting node_modules and running `npm install` again but that didn't help.

Comment: What the version of Angular/RXJS do you have in your app?

Comment: I reverted back to the previous commit and the issue seems to be when I added tslint-angular. However, uninstalling it doesn't solve the problem?!

Comment: @RomanA. Angular: 9.1.12

Comment: Have you tried to remove node_modules and install them again? Also, reinstall rxjs

Comment: @RomanA. Yes, I said that I removed node_modules as the first step. I'll try reinstall rxjs.

Answer (score 0):

The error was the clue. I had tried to address empty() from rxjs being deprecated and incorrectly used their recommendation of using the `EMPTY` constant and the `of()` method with no parameters.

I replaced that with `new Observable<>()` and it built fine.